# init() failing with OAuthException

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, apache-flex, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I am trying to use the FacebookMobile Graph API for actionscript 3.  When I run
    FacebookMobile.init(MY_AP_ID, facebookInitHandler);

My callback is getting null for the success object and false is an Error saying "OAuthException" "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

I am getting this error on both IOS and Android.  Is it possible I set something up wrong on the facebook site?

This is being thrown in init() so I am not trying to query anything about any user yet.  I have spent hours with this with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if(FacebookMobile.getSession() == null){
                FacebookMobile.init(MY_AP_ID, facebookInitHandler);
            }

 //sets facebook session
        private function facebookInitHandler(success:Object, fail:Object):void{
            if(success != null){
                trace("facebook init success");
                //publish_stream is required to post messages to the wall 
                FacebookMobile.login(facebookLoginHandler, stage, ["publish_stream"]);
            }else{
                trace("Facebook initialization falied- " + String(fail.error.message));
                displayGeneralAlert("An error occurred", "Unable to initialize Facebook component");
            }
        }
```

Comment: How can you get this error on iOS if it can't run flash?

Comment: I am running it in Adobe Flex, which uses AS3, and runs on IOS.  I hope this wasn't the reason my question was -1'd

Comment: can you paste the full oauthexception? they generally have the reason there. my advice is to get it working first on the web (js, php, whatever) to eliminate something wrong in your workflow

Comment: That is the full oauthexception.  "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

Comment: @jln646v same thing happens to me using flex. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that a bug has been logged for this problem and there is a fix for that: http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/issues/detail?id=402

But anyway, without using the fix above, what I'm doing is if I don't get the success object at init I'm using login method and callback that is being invoke after this has all necessary things including accessToken. Next you can use api method to get other things you need.